# Sandwich button and Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, header, responsive

I need your assistance. Please take a look to my code and say to me what's wrong, since my sandwich button doesn't work. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div>
        <!--here is my sandwich button !-->
        <img class="nav_menu" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_button.png" alt="button" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <!--Here is cross button to close the sandwich button!-->
        <img class="nav_close" src="templates/shablon/images/menu_close.png" alt="cross_button" />
    </div>
    <div id="top_menu_outer">
        <div id="header_inner">
            <div id="top_menu">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top_menu" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.nav_menu").click(function() {
        $('#top_menu_outer').addClass("_opened");
    });
    $("img.only_mobile.nav_close ").click(function() {
        $('#top_menu_outer').removeClass("_opened");
    });
    var buttonUp = $('#up-button');
    var currentScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop >= 200) {
            buttonUp.fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            buttonUp.fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    buttonUp.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about doesn´t work, what does not work?

Comment: Please put full html code.

Comment: @Knitesh not full code, but a [mcve]. We don't need everything, just what's relevant to the issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox perfect..

Comment: What is the `.only_mobile` in your `$("img.only_mobile.nav_close")`